# Addition program crashes when I give it input

Tags: c, arrays

I'm a C beginner, and this is by far my biggest program yet. It incorporates do while loops to restart the program, allow the user to add as many numbers as they want and ensure the correct letters are submitted for yes or no. Simple enough. Thing is, every number that I type adds up to 0.00, and the program gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped) error regardless of my choice for restart.

Errors:

[image: Program Errors]

I'm well aware that this could be some stupid detail I overlooked, but bear with me! Help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
/*Basic addition program*/
/*May 31 2018*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char restart;

//Loop for restart
do{
    /*
    Starts Variables for Current number, sum,
    number place count, and restart choice
    */
    float currnum, sum;
    int count = 1;
    char restart = 'N';

    //Loop for user input amount until 0 is submitted
    do{

    //Initiates number place ending array
    char end[3];

    printf("Basic Addition Program\nType 0 To Terminate\n\n");

    //Chooses which ending to add to array
    if(count == 1){
        strcpy(end, "st");
    }else if(count == 2){
        strcpy(end, "nd");
    }else if(count == 3){
        strcpy(end, "rd");
    }else if(count > 3){
        strcpy(end, "th");
    }

    //Requests user input and adds to current number float
    printf("Enter %d%s number: ", count, end);
    scanf(" %d", &currnum);

    //Clears Screen (Unix)
    system("clear");

    //Adds current number to overall sum
    sum += currnum;

    //Increases number count so that places shift by 1 (e.g 1st to 2nd)
    count++;


    }while(currnum != 0);

    //States numbers inputted and sum
    printf("You added %d numbers and got a sum of %.2f\n", count, sum);

    //Do while loop for user error
    do{
        printf("Restart?(Y/N): ");
        scanf(" %c", restart);

        //Tests if numbers have ben inputted in lowercase and corrects accordingly
        if(restart == 'y'){
            restart = 'Y';
        }else if(restart == 'n'){
            restart = 'N';
        }
    }while(restart != 'Y' || restart != 'N' );

    }while(restart == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: In fact, what does your compiler say? How are you compiling your code?

Comment: You have two ***different*** variables named `restart`. One inside the outer loop, and one outside the loop. The variable outside the loop is what is used in the loop condition, and it is never initialized and will therefore have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. It should have been very easy to detect by stepping through the code line by line in a debugger. So please learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: -------------- Run: Debug in Super Math (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /home/mat/CPROJECTS/C/UNIXFiles/Super Math/bin/Debug/Super Math
Executing: gnome-terminal -t Super\ Math -x  /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/mat/CPROJECTS/C/UNIXFiles/Super\ Math/bin/Debug/Super\ Math  (in /home/mat/CPROJECTS/C/UNIXFiles/Super Math/.)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: I compile with gcc on codeblocks

Comment: Then you should configure codeblocks to pass `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2` as compiler options.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your program output is plain text. Please do not paste screenshots from text. Instead add the text as text into your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problematic statement is

```
scanf(" %c", restart); /* you need to provide the &(address) to store */
```

It should be

```
scanf(" %c", &restart);
```

you should read the compiler warning & solve yourself & compile with `-Wall` flag.

Also below statement

```
scanf("%d", &currnum); /* currnum is declared as float variable, use %f */
```

In the below code block

```
char restart;
do {

 /* some code */
}while(restart == 'Y');
```

the `restart` is not initialized, your compiler could have warn you like

> error: ‘restart’ is used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Werror=uninitialized]

So at the very first initialize `restart` like

```
char restart = 'Y';
```

and finally if you want to learn C properly, treat all warnings as error & then start solving problems. for e.g compile like below

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```